# Configure NancyFx dependency injection at runtime

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

I am working on a side-project involving a small self-hosted Nancy server for the local network to remotely control a media player. To enable support for multiple players I implemented a simple plugin mechanism like it was outlined here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62

The dynamic loading and execution works great, but the problem I am running into is how to tell TinyIoC which plugin implementation to use. At the moment I have a subdirectory named plugins where the .dlls are stored and at startup TinyIoC discovers the one test dll in this directory and wires up the dependency without me choosing anything explicitly.

I found the method Bootstrapper.ConfigureApplicationContainer to be the place to do DI configuration but since I want to use a dynamic system and do not have the server project a reference to all plugin assemblies that is not sufficient in my case.

Is this even possible with TinyIoC or do I need to look for another IoC container?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you considered Managed Extensibility Framework instead of TinyIoc?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this suits your needs, but it's suggestion anyway: You could have each of the plugins do its own container configuration, by having each of them provide an implementation of [`IRegistrations`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/IRegistrations.cs) in plugins .dll.

Nancy will pick implmentations of `IRegistrations` up automatically - as long the assemblies are loaded at startup - and execute them during application startup.

Alternatively you could scan the plugins directory yourself in the `Bootstrapper.ConfigureApplicationContainer` method and scan the plugin .dlls for either `IRegistrations` or your own custom hook.